# basic insertion sort in linked list with logic problem (maybe it is because pointer)

Tags: c++, sorting

I write a code for insertion sort for integer data in linked list in c++, I referred to the algorithms on the Internet, and finally took the following code using array as a basic concept for my version.
however, the sorting always ignore my first element,(but all the other element is ordered well).

I have tried checking my loop statement, checking the pointer address while looping (because my key pointer loop at first time didn't go into the judge pointer loop), checking the shifting mechanism while comparing, but I cannot find my logic problem.

(I know someone would said I doesn't provide enough data for you to help me, but I have been checking these things for two days, including asking friends and searching the solutions existed on website. So I really hope someone can answer me without blame, thank you.)

array version(on the internet)

```
#include <iostream>
void InsertionSort(int *arr, int size){
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (key < arr[j] && j >= 0) {
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

linked list version(by my own)

Node class used in my version

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        next = NULL;
        pre = NULL;
    }
    Node(int n)
    {
        data = n;
        next = NULL;
        pre = NULL;
    }
    int getData() { return data; }
    Node *getNext() { return next; }
    Node *getPre() { return pre; }
    void setData(int d) { data = d; }
    void setNext(Node *n) { next = n; }
    void setPre(Node *p) { pre = p; }
private:
    int data;
    Node *next, *pre;
};
```

```
class List
{
public:
    List() { list = NULL; }
    List(int n) { generate(n); }

    void generate(int n)
    {
        int j;
        list = NULL;
        for(j = 0;j < n;j ++)
            generate();
    }

    void generate()
    {
        Node *buf = new Node(rand());
        buf->setNext(list); //list->NODE2.next->NODE1.next->NULL
        if(list != NULL)
            list->setPre(buf);
        list = buf;
    }
    void insertionSort()
    {
        bool breakByCompare;
        Node* keyptr;
        Node* judgeptr;// judge is the value that is going to compare with key
        int key;
        for(keyptr = list->getNext(); keyptr != NULL; 
            keyptr = keyptr->getNext()){
            //if we set list as 5,7,6 ; 6 is key
            key = keyptr->getData();//store the key value for the setting after shifting
            breakByCompare = 0;

            for(judgeptr = keyptr->getPre() ; judgeptr->getPre()!= NULL; 
                judgeptr= judgeptr->getPre()){
                //list: 5,7,6 ; 7 is judge

                if(judgeptr->getData() > key){
                    // 7>6, so we shift 7 to the position which was for 6

                    judgeptr->getNext()->setData(judgeptr->getData());// list: 5,7,7 ;
                    cout << judgeptr->getData() << " , " << keyptr->getData() << endl;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            judgeptr->getNext()->setData(key);// list: 5,6,7
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        Node *cur = list;
        while(cur != NULL)
        {
            cout<<cur->getData()<<" ";
            cur = cur->getNext();
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
private:
    Node *list;
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    List *l = new List(10);
    l->print();
    l->insertionSort();
    l->print();

}
```

Comment: Strange bit of code here `List *l = new List(10); l = new List(10);` Why are you allocating your list twice?

Comment: I think to help here we need to see the `List` constructor. The problem could be the way you set up your list rather than the way you sort it.

Comment: @john, thank you, I forgot to put all the list class in, I have edited.

Comment: @john the code is a mistake, it is originally for the other sorting function test for different value ~ I have edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important difference between a linked list and an array is that it is sometimes required to handle the first element as a special case.

Here is a fixed version of your sorting method :

```
void insertionSort()
{
    bool breakByCompare;
    Node* keyptr;
    Node* judgeptr;
    int key;
    for(keyptr = list->getNext(); keyptr != NULL;  keyptr = keyptr->getNext()){
        
        key = keyptr->getData();
        breakByCompare = 0;
        
        // I replaced judgeptr->getPre() by judgeptr in the condition
        // to allow the backward loop to go until the root
        for(judgeptr = keyptr->getPre() ; judgeptr != NULL;  judgeptr= judgeptr->getPre()){
            
            if(judgeptr->getData() > key){
                judgeptr->getNext()->setData(judgeptr->getData());
                cout << judgeptr->getData() << " , " << key << endl;
            }
            else break;
        }
        // Here is the special case : we must support a null judgeptr 
        // and replace its next element by the list
        if (judgeptr) judgeptr->getNext()->setData(key);
        else list->setData(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question with more information in the list class. And the way I use doesn't change the node position, but only shift the data in the node~ for instance, 7,2,8 becomes 7,7,8 (shifting) becomes 2,7,8(put key at front) , which means I don't have to change the list pointer right? because my list pointer is always at the first node of list. Sorry for lack of information before.

Comment: In the other hand, could you explain more detail about how my sorting treat the list first element, which is also the list pointer, as the special case so it ignore it? is it because of the loop condition that is not satisfied or any other address problem I never think of.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstoud you, I edited my post which now propose a fix.